# Update a table data on menu click

Tags: php, html, css, ajax

I want to create an accordion MENU (Don't know if it will be created using `divs` or `<ul>`) and when I click on a submenu I need to execute a `mysql query`.
I mean, when I click on the submenu I need to update the data/content of the table that is beside the menu. I'm not sure how to do it and/or if its better to use `Ajax` or `PHP`, I'm new to both.

All I could do so far is to create the accordion menu using divs.

```
<?php 
    include("conexao.php");

function loadTable(){
    $pdo = conectar();
    $query_select = $pdo->prepare("SELECT prof.nome AS PROFESSOR, disc.nome AS DISCIPLINA, prof.ch AS ch
                                    FROM professor prof 
                                    INNER JOIN prof_disc pd ON prof.id = pd.fk_prof
                                    INNER JOIN disciplina disc ON pd.fk_disc = disc.id");
    $query_select->execute();

    $line = $query_select->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    foreach($line as $row){
        echo "
            <h3><span class='arrow-r'></span>".$row->PROFESSOR."</h3>
            <div style='display: none;' class=''>
                <p>".$row->DISCIPLINA."</p>
            </div>
        ";
    }   
    echo '</table>';
}
 ?>
```

We'll have something like:
`PROFESSOR | DISCIPLINA`
`Math -    | History`
`Geografia | Physics`

Comment: this will refresh the entire page, so you need to use AJAX and JSON

Comment: @Saedawke Thanks! Would you mind to give me some kind of example of the event handler. Not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Complementing `Jojo01` answer in how to use `post` in Ajax:

```
var value1 = "somevalue";
var productsURL = "getproducts.php?key1="+value1;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: productsURL,
    cache: false,
    success: function(result){
        //do something with result
    }
});
```

In your `PHP` file (`getproducts.php`) you may have a variable for the value/key you sent using ajax and then fetch the database for some value, when you have the value, you can just `echo` it and it will return to the `result` variable in the Ajax code.

e.g. (it will be something like that)

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["key1"])) {
        $key1 = $_POST["key1"];

        $sql = "SELECT column1 FROM table1 WHERE key1=".$key1;
        //fetch values from database
        //get values

        echo $values;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a new mysql query to be executed when you click on a submenu download [jQuery](http://jquery.com). When you have jQuery use the jQuery [.click()](https://api.jquery.com/click/) function and [.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) function.

**Edit:**

Handle the event like this:

Ps. The jQuery selecting logic is the same as in css.

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
  $("#subMenuItemId").click(function() 
  {
    //Post action here
  });
});
```

Comment: Could you give me an example of the event ? Not sure how to control it.

Comment: There you go. I'm not sure how to use the .post() because i have never used it before... But you can browse the web for an answer to that.